# How to set multiline in SweetDialog?

Tags: android, dialog

In my string

```
message = "This is a multiline message."+
                    "\nSecond line."+
                    "\n\nFourth line after a line gap."+
                    "\nThis is fifth line.";
```

When I setText for my Dialog but content not show multiline in Dialog.

This is my code in xml:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/pading_top_min"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:maxLines="16"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
```

Please help me with this problem. 
Thanks very much.

Comment: use html tag and set html text.

Comment: where you call string value?

Answer (score 0):

\n should work, but you could try with html instead

```
textView.setText(fromHtml("This is a multiline message.<br/>Second line.<br/><br/>Fourth line after a line gap.<br/>This is fifth line."));
```